# Can you please help me identify this lovely houseplant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

Green, heart-shaped leaves, grows upwards on strong stalks/stems.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like *Peperomia*, and judging from the shape of the leaves I would say a raindrop *Peperomia* (*P. polybotrya*).

The *Peperomia* likes bright but indirect light, and warm temperatures. I have one on a north-east facing window, so it gets only a little bit of direct sunlight very early in the morning in summertime.

Watering: let the soil dry up completely before watering. Don't treat it as a swamp plant, the roots will rot when soil stays wet all the time.